# MemoryError: when I run negex.py

Tags: python

I am using negex to find the negation terms in my text along with the negation scope. This is the negex.py :
https://github.com/chapmanbe/negex/blob/master/negex.python/negex.py
This is my wrapper function to call negex on each phrase for each sentence of my input text:

```
input_text = ' Today the weather is not great for playing baseball.
 it is snowing and the wind is strong.
 I wish it was sunny but it is not what I want.
 Today is Sunday and I have to go to school tomorrow.
 Tommorrow is not going to be snowing though.'
```

wrapper function:

```
for report in data_samples:
    this_txt, this_sentences = sentences_for_text(report)

    for i in range(len(this_txt)):
        this_string = this_txt[i]
        my_sentences = this_sentences[i]

       for sntc in my_sentences:
           my_ngrams = find_ngrams(sntc)

          for grm in my_ngrams:
             tagger = negTagger(sentence = sntc, phrases = grm, rules = irules, negP=False)

             if 'negated' in tagger.getNegationFlag():
                 print("tagger.getScopes():", tagger.getScopes())
                 output.append([this_string, grm])
                 output.append(tagger.getScopes())
```

So each `report` can have more than one segment, I get each segment in the report and I break it into sentences, I extract all the unigram, bigram, trigram and forgrams for each `sntc`, and I go through all the grams for each sentence to find the negation in the sentence. This code is working, but the problem is it uses so much memory, and before even finishing one report I get `MemoryError:`. I need to run this for thousands of reports, any idea how can I fix this problem given that I only care about `negated` tag?

Comment: what is the type of your `data_samples` ? and how big is it ?

Comment: `data_samples` is a list of texts--- in the real application, will contain couple thousands of text, each text has around 5 sentences, each text is a string --.

Comment: @arthur I figured it out. The problem was `grm` should be in a form of a list not an string. So I simply should replace `grm` with `[grm]` and that works correctly and fast.